# Differentiable manifold?

Tags: analysis

Let $f\colon \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3$ be defined by the formula
$$
f(x,y)=(\sin x,e^y\cos x,xy).
$$

Simultaneously $y \geq 0$ and  $0 < x < 2\pi$.

The question is whether $f$ is differentiable manifold or not? And why?

Comment: It's a bit of an abuse of notation to refer to the function $f$ as a differentiable manifold. I think the question you should be asking is whether the graph of $f$ is a differentiable manifold.

Comment: The graph or the image?

Comment: I do believe I meant the graph, i.e. the subset of $\mathbb{R}^5$ consisting of points $(x,y, \sin x, (e^y)\cos x, xy)$ and subject to the given constraints on $x,y$.

Comment: $f$ is a parameterization of a surface: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot3d%28sin+x%2C+e%5Ey+cos+x%2C+xy%29 and the response is yes, 'cuz the jacobian $Jf$ has rank two everywhere

Comment: It is a manifold with boundary.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: The inverse function theorem and implicit function theorem allow you to construct a differentiable atlas for the graph of any (nice) smooth function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$. Can you see how?